# Is qiskit documentation about determining $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ incorrect?

Tags: programming, machine-learning, openpulse

I'm using pi-pulse pulses on qubit Armonk for determining 0 and 1 by Machine Learning. But when I run the code from https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html. I get an incorrect distribution of states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$.

[image: my problem]

For example, in the Qiskit textbook, this image looks like:

[image: correct image]

About 3 months ago, the image that I got by using this textbook was correct, but now it's not.
When I use Machine Learning for old states, I get excellent results, but now my algorithms have failed on this task.

Please, help me with my problem. I don't know, how to fix it. Why did this happen? That is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what's gone wrong when you ran it the second time but for what it's worth, that doesn't look right. I've run the notebook through again myself and I have a ground state cluster around (-16.4, -8.6) and an excited state cluster around (-13.0, -14.5). So it looks like the qubit was in the ground state in both experiments when you measured (if the system parameters haven't changed drastically since March, which it appears to have done so since the textbook image).